# Ошибка JSON.parse в коде капчи

Tags: javascript, json

В консоли браузера выдает ошибку по первой строчке,я понимаю что что-то не так,но не могу понять где именно, в онлайн код инспекторах тоже пишет ошибку по первой строчке.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
> the JSON data

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    
                    let tk = '';
                    
                grecaptcha.ready(function() {
                  grecaptcha.execute('ключ сайта', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
                    tk = token;
                    document.getElementById('token').value = token;
                    
                    const data = new URLSearchParams();
                    for (const pair of new FormData(document.querySelector('form'))) {
                            data.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
                    }
                    
                    fetch('send.php', {
                        method: 'post',
                        body: data,
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(result => {
                        if (result['om_score'] >= 0.5) {
                            console.log('Human')
                        } else {
                            console.log('Bot')
                        }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ошибку пишет в самом json'e. Надо его смотреть

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку нашел,не хватало точки с запятой в php коде